# Who is using Koa?

Tags: community

Anyone know of some sites I could check out that are using the Koa community template? I'm trying to get a better idea of what I can really do with these templates.

Comment: Most likely people that are not going to give you links to their community. I suggest just playing with it for a bit to see what it can/can't do.

Comment: I would also advise talking to your salesforce rep. Sometimes they are willing to connect you with their other customers to demonstrate functionality. Or build out an environment as a demonstration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this document?  http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/18/en-us/sfdc/pdf/community_templates.pdf

it gives the details on what each template can do and how it can be used.  As pointed out earlier the best way to get an understanding of the different themes is to create a sandbox environment and test them out for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I have been looking for more of a dev guide to communities.